# Refactoring multiple jQuery on click functions into one function

Tags: javascript, jquery

What's the best way to create one dynamic function so I'm not constantly writing multiple similar functions?

```
$("#litigation-click").click(function() {
    $(".textbox-analysis").hide()
    $("#litigation-box").fadeIn("slow",function() {});
    $("html, body").animate({ scrollTop: $(document).height() }, "slow");

    return false;
});

$("#goingconcern-click").click(function(){
    $(".textbox-analysis").hide()
    $("#goingconcern-box").fadeIn("slow",function(){});
    $("html, body").animate({scrollTop: $(document).height()},"slow");

    return false;
});

$("#unquoted-click").click(function() {
    $(".textbox-analysis").hide()
    $("#unquoted-box").fadeIn("slow",function(){});
    $("html, body").animate({ scrollTop: $(document).height() }, "slow");

    return false;
});
```

Comment: Could you please add a sample of your HTML. Specifically we would need to see how the `#X-click` elements relate to the `#X-box` elements

Comment: why? Just leave it. Does refactoring make it better to read. I doubt it. Is there lots of reuse, not really. Just leave it be

Comment: I assume he has more than three listeners here and just posted a sample.

Comment: even so the re-factoring is likely going to be just as "wordy".

Comment: @Liam Not in the slightest. Instead of having to repeat this same click handler N times for every `X-click` element it can easily be changed so one handler can work for an infinite number of elements. All we need to know is how to traverse the DOM that OP has created with his HTML.

Answer (score 0):

You could use comma separator for multiple selectors, then split clicked `id` to get the first part and use it to generate box `id` :

```
$("#unquoted-click, #goingconcern-click, #unquoted-click").click(function() {
    $(".textbox-analysis").hide();

    $("#" + this.id.split('-')[0] + "-box").fadeIn("slow",function(){});
    $("html, body").animate({ scrollTop: $(document).height() }, "slow");

    return false;
});
```

> If you can populate your HTML code may we could find another way to get the box  relatively.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

You can write a function with a **parameter**. E.g.

```
function Clicked(elClicked) {
  $(".textbox-analysis").hide()
  $(elClicked).fadeIn("slow",function() {
  });
  $("html, body").animate({ scrollTop: $(document).height() }, "slow");
  return false;
}
```

then call that function in your click event with an argument of the elements id that has been clicked

```
$("#litigation-click, #goingconcern-click, #unquoted-click").click(function() {
     Clicked("#" + $(this).attr('id'));
});
```

`$(this).attr('id')` gets the id of the element clicked.

Answer (score -1):

You can use [jQuery Multiple Selector (“selector1, selector2, selectorN”)](https://api.jquery.com/multiple-selector/) & `event`object to get the target element

```
  $("#litigation-click, #unquoted-click, #goingconcern-click").click(function(event) {
  $(".textbox-analysis").hide();
  var _getId = event.target.id; // will give target element
  $("#"+_getId).fadeIn("slow",function() {
  });
  $("html, body").animate({ scrollTop: $(document).height() }, "slow");
  return false;
});
```

Comment: But how would you know whether to select `#litigation-box`, `#unquoted-box` or `#goingconcern-box`?

Comment: You are right when you asked how will I know the event target. But if you check the click handler all are doing same work. if it is the case he should have used a common class.

Comment: I completely agree. However this is only half an answer.

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan sorry I missed overlook one line in his code.

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan thanks for pointing out. I have edited the answer